# Printing a single column in the data frame tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

The code below gets the `mean,median,max,min` as a pandas table. I just want to print the `Average` portion of the table without the dates. The `print(*out["Average"].iloc[:, 1], sep="\n")` should do that but I get an error with that function. How would I be able to fix that?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

date_list = ['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00','2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-12-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-02-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-04-01 00:00:00','2021-05-01 00:00:00', '2021-06-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-07-01 00:00:00']
monthly_values = np.array([ 15., 39.6, 0.2, 34.3, 19.6, 26.8, 15.7, 26., 12.6, 15.5, 18.6, 2.3, 6.5,
   2.5, 12.2, 11.6, 93.9, 25.5, 26.5, -16.5, -1.4, -1.8, 5.])

data = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_list, "Averages": monthly_values})
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
out=(data.groupby(data["Date"].dt.year)
     .agg(['mean','median','max','min'])
     .droplevel(0,1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x:'Average' if x=='mean' else x.title()))
print(*out["Average"].iloc[:, 1], sep="\n")
```

Error:

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Expected output:

```
22.275
14.158333333333333
18.742857142857144
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Running your code prints expected output.

Comment: I am not sure as to why that is I use python 3.7 on windows 10 I reached out to some people and they said they had no problem running the code as well. But I have tested it multiple times and I get the `Error` output.

Comment: No problems here also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `out['Average']` just gives a series, and so you don't need an `.iloc`:

```
In [56]: out['Average']
Out[56]:
Date
2019    22.275000
2020    14.158333
2021    18.742857
Name: Average, dtype: float64

In [57]: print(*out['Average'], sep="\n")
22.275
14.158333333333333
18.74285714285714
```

It's possible that your `groupby` could yield a dataframe under other circumstances, in which case you might need that `iloc` indexing to just pick off one series.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `iloc` only takes one argument.  This works:

```
print(out["Average"])
```

Comment: I get this type error : `TypeError: print() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64`

Comment: @georgehere, my mistake, I've removed the ```*``` in the print statement, which was required to print an iterable using delimiters.

Comment: I see but that only gives me `14.158333333333333` as the output. I need the values for the entire column like shown on the expected outputs

Comment: @georgehere, I've edited my answer.  You really don't need the ```iloc``` indexer at all